# Make a div a link and change the content on hover

Tags: css, html, hover

I am trying to make a div a link, and this works, not sure if i have done it correctly.
But i also want the type in the div to change color. Could anyone help me and if you explain a bit i will be greatfull :D Trying to learn :)

Here is the html

```
    <div class="song_feature">
        <a href="#"></a>
        <div class="song_feature_content">
            <div class="break32"></div>
            <h1>1</h1>
            <div class="break10"></div>
            <div class="break45"></div>
            <h2>Lorem ipsum title</h2>
            <div class="break10"></div>
            <p>lorem ipsum</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And the css

```
.song_feature:hover {
background-color: #B5B5B5;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: First of all what is your question , be more specific about your question

Answer (score 6):

Just try this in your CSS:

```
.song_feature:link {
  background-color: #000;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.song_feature:visited {
  background-color: #000;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.song_feature:hover {
  background-color: #B5B5B5;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.song_feature:active {
  background-color: #000;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

The background color will be black until the mouse hovers over it. Just change the color accordingly.

Comment: Ok, cool, thanks :)
But i am also trying to change the color of the text when you roll over. I have gotten the text to change color when i roll over the text but not the div. Is there any way to make it change when i roll over the div?

Comment: Hmm, I'm sure you can but I don't know how. Perhaps consider adding this to the question and being more specific so that people can help you.

Answer (score 2):

First of all wrap the `a` around the `div`

```
<div class="song_feature">
    <a href="#">
    <div class="song_feature_content">
        <div class="break32"></div>
        <h1>1</h1>
        <div class="break10"></div>
        <div class="break45"></div>
        <h2>Lorem ipsum title</h2>
        <div class="break10"></div>
        <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    </div>
       </a>
</div>
```

And if by 'type in the div' you mean the text (i am guessing here) type `color:#your color` like this :

```
 .song_feature:hover {
 background-color: #B5B5B5;
  cursor: pointer;
 } 

 .song_feature:hover a {
    color:#edc844;/*some random color*/
  }
```

This works in IE7+, latest Mozilla, Safari, Chrome

Comment: maybe this one of the solution but I see the way you code it!! `div` inside `a` make **w3c** error

Comment: Im trying this but the text does not change color when i roll over the div aerea.

Comment: The `<a>` tag doesn't inherit colors from parent elements. But don't fear because the solution is here. I reedited my answer.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, your issue is with getting this to validate. Historically, the `a` element was inline, and as such was not technically allowed to encompass block level elements like `div`.

Note that I didn't say “couldn't” encompass them: block level links have pretty much always worked as you'd expect, it just wouldn't pass validation. With HTML5 [paving the cowpaths](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-design-principles/#pave-the-cowpaths), this has now been amended. As per this [HTML Doctor](http://html5doctor.com/block-level-links-in-html-5/) article:

> One new and exciting thing you can do in HTML 5 is wrap links round “block-level” elements... removing duplication and creating a much wider hit area to click.

In short, @Tbi45's solution is the way to go: wrap your `a` around the `div`. It reduces repetition, validates (as HTML5) and doesn't require JavaScript.

Check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cherryflavourpez/LPmPx/) for an example. The important CSS is:

```
.song_feature>a {
    display: block;
}
```

Which ensures that the entire contents of your `div` is clickable.

Answer (score 0):

This is easier to do if you use jQuery.

HTML:

```
<div class="song_feature">
    <a href="#" id="hover">Hover here</a>
    <div class="song_feature_content">
        <div class="break32"></div>
        <h1>1</h1>
        <div class="break10"></div>
        <div class="break45"></div>
        <h2>Lorem ipsum title</h2>
        <div class="break10"></div>
        <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('#hover').hover(function(){
    $('.song_feature').css('background-color', '#f00');
});
```

run: http://jsfiddle.net/cS6h8/

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you do the opposite.

```
<a href="#" class="song_feature">
    <div class="song_feature_content">
        <div class="break32"></div>
        <h1>1</h1>
        <div class="break10"></div>
        <div class="break45"></div>
        <h2>Lorem ipsum title</h2>
        <div class="break10"></div>
        <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    </div>
</a>

.song_feature {
    display: block;
}

.song_feature:hover {
    background-color: #B5B5B5;
}
```